# Check if module exists in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm dynamically defining a module name from an argument passed on the cli, for example `Required::Module::#{ARGV.first}`

Is there any way to check if that module exists? Also, how would I run methods on it not knowing it's exact name?

Comment: Interesting.  There is no straight answer here, and noteworthy machination is required.  Good Question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check for module existence using the `const_get` method:

```
begin
    mod = Required::Module::const_get "ModuleName"
    #It exists
rescue NameError
    #Doesn't exist
end
```

Comment: I do not believe exception handling is the best approach, it's both slow and bloated (code-wise). Use `const_defined?` instead.

Comment: You should edit the answer to do something like `mod = Required::Module.const_defined?("ModuleName") ? Required::Module::const_get "ModuleName" : nil`

Comment: Note that if the module is known statically it's easier to just use `Required::Module::ModuleName` - both will through `NameError`. This is useful if the module name is only known at runtime though.

Comment: Do not forget to pass inherited = false as a second argument, it is important. Otherwise you will conflict with ancestors.

Answer (score 37):

Use `const_defined?` for this.

```
Required::Module.const_defined?(:ModuleName)
```

returns true or false.

Comment: Now can it:
`Module.const_defined?(:Name)`
it return true or false

Comment: @SunTechnique It does not return false, it raises a `NameError`

Answer (score 14):

```
defined?(Required::Module)
```

gives `"constant"` if it exists, and `nil` if it doesn't.

**Update**: Sorry, didn't read your question properly.

```
defined?(eval("Required::Module::"+string))
```

should give you what you're after.

Comment: But this doesn't seem to work with dynamically named modules, for example `defined?("Parade::Procedure::#{procedure.capitalize}")` returns `"expression"`, even though the module I'm calling doesn't exist.

Comment: I'd want to avoid using `eval`, especially if `string` is a user entered value. You could cause some serious damage.  (read more about it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty)

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if:

- a constant referring to a module exists,
- an object that the constant holds reference to is a module.

Try that:

```
 def module_exists?(name, base = self.class)
   base.const_defined?(name) && base.const_get(name).instance_of?(::Module)
 end
```

Then in your code:

```
 module_exists?(ARGV.first, Required::Module)
```

It will return `true` if there is a module of the given name within a given namespace base. The difference from the examples given in other answers is that it will return `false` if the queried name reffers to a class, not to a module.

#### Include classes in a test

If you want to change that behavior and force the method to also return `true` for classes (not just modules) change `instance_of?` to `is_a?`.

#### OOP way

You can also code it in a more object-oriented way if your `Required::Module` module is the only module you're testing for submodules:

```
 module Required::Module
   def submodule_exists?(name)
     const_defined?(name) && const_get(name).instance_of?(::Module)
   end
 end
 module_function :submodule_exists?
```

Then in your code:

```
 Required::Module.submodule_exists?(ARGV.first)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you got ActiveSupport

```
mod = ("Required::Module::#{ARGV.first}".constantize rescue nil)
```

Comment: I don’t think this makes sense as there’s cleaner native way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you `require` something that extends something else, you can't base your test on a constant because the extension may not define a new one. Instead, base it on the presence of something else, like a new method.

I use the below to test if [open_uri_redirections](https://rubygems.org/gems/open_uri_redirections) has been required:

```
if OpenURI.methods.include?(:redirectable_safe?)
  # extension loaded
else
  # extension not loaded
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The currently selected answer is not correct.  `const_get` and `const_defined` look for any constant name, regardless of the object calling that method.  For example, if I wanted to check for `MyModule::Rails` inside a Rails application, using `const_get` would return the normal Rails module.

To check for a constant within a specific namespace, use the `constants` method and check for your class:

> MyModule.constants.include?("Rails") # => false

Comment: Kudos. In the manner of `instance_methods` etc., `const_defined?` includes a second parameter of `true` (default, inheritance is considered) and `false` (only search the receiver). I think I prefer using that even though it's a rather ambiguous boolean property, because there's a good chance that the Ruby interpreter will have a more optimised search than creating a Ruby array via `constants` and asking Ruby to search it with `include?`.

Answer (score 0):

Get the class if it exists:

```
dynamic_klass = "Required::Module::#{ARGV.first}".classify.safe_constantize
```

Call a method on the class if it does:

```
dynamic_klass.send("some_method") if dynamic_klass.present?
```