# Dynamically define named classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, dsl, metaclass

I am writing an internal DSL in Ruby.  For this, I need to programmatically create named classes and nested classes.  What is the best way to do so?  I recon that there are two ways to do so:

1. Use `Class.new` to create an anonymous class, then use `define_method` to add methods to it, and finally call `const_set` to add them as named constants to some namespace.
2. Use some sort of `eval`

I've tested the first way and it worked, but being new to Ruby, I am not sure that putting classes as constants is the right way.

Are there other, better ways?  If not, which of the above is preferable?

Comment: `eval` is best avoided. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you want to create a class with a dynamic name, you'll have to do almost exactly what you said. However, you do not need to use `define_method`. You can just pass a block to `Class.new` in which you initialize the class. This is semantically identical to the contents of `class`/`end`.

Remember with `const_set`, to be conscientious of the receiver (`self`) in that scope. If you want the class defined globally you will need to call `const_set` on the TopLevel module (which varies in name and detail by Ruby).

```
a_new_class = Class.new(Object) do
  attr_accessor :x

  def initialize(x)
    print #{self.class} initialized with #{x}"
    @x = x
  end
end

SomeModule.const_set("ClassName", a_new_class)

c = ClassName.new(10)

...
```

Comment: I should also mention, class names are constants inherently. They're defined as constants of the module they're contained in.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the name of the top-level module?

Answer (score 5):

You don't really need to use `const_set`. The return value of `Class.new` can be assigned to
a constant and the block of `Class.new` is `class_eval`.

```
class Ancestor; end
SomeClass = Class.new(Ancestor) do
  def initialize(var)
     print "#{self.class} initialized with #{var}"
  end
end
=> SomeClass
SomeClass.new("foo")
# SomeClass initialized with foo=> #<SomeClass:0x668b68>
```

Comment: This does not create a class with a dynamic name. SomeClass is statically determined.

Comment: Not really. Constant name will be dedeuced when the class is being used for something. https://gist.github.com/1064909

Comment: in your example, you're defining your new class to "SomeClass". The example you just pasted contradicts your statement that "You don't really need to use const_set". You do need to use it to bind something to a module constant.

Comment: In that sense you are right I thought you meant "a class wth a dynamic name" to be == anon class.

Answer (score 4):

Should be like this

```
a_new_class = Class.new(Object) do

attr_accessor :x

 def initialize(x)
  @x = x
 end
end

SomeModule = Module.new
SomeModule.const_set("ClassName", a_new_class)

c = SomeModule::ClassName.new(10)
```