# How can I read config variables from Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I have read [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/activeadmin/frames) I did not find how to do this.

I need to get `default_namespace` setting.

Also if you could explain the process of find that method would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default_namespace variable is defined in Active Admin via the application.rb file

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/9a9693b541460b43cafdb39e67247ae0a3a892b8/lib/active_admin/application.rb

This should help you find the correct call to get what you're looking for.

Comment: hehehe thanks, you told me how to fish. I am going to put response here, for the ones who want just the solution `ActiveAdmin.application.default_namespace`

Comment: Another question I am using `my_admin_route_root_path`, I was thinking to use it as `eval "#{ ActiveAdmin.application.default_namespace }_root_path"` is this bad for some reason?

Comment: There isn't really a yes / no answer for this.  I would suggest that eval be avoided wherever there is a possibility of a user interactive with the string you are eval'ing.  Basically, putting in an eval when a simple variable could be used raise the risk of arbitrary code execution.  Further info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty

Comment: PS - Tip, now that Github allows you to search for code within a repo, it's super easy to find this kind of stuff now.  This is a relatively recent update, but one of the most useful things they've ever done I think

Comment: How can I search for code?, I found a way but seems is not throwing good results, with the input that is in the top bar.

Comment: About eval, I was thinking about using  `send(ActiveAdmin.application.default_namespace)`, instead of `eval`. I don't imagine how injection could happen in my case, I suppose I save the effort of thinking this using `send`, but I am not sure.