# How to convert ruby formatted json string to json hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to access json string like hash object so that i can access json using key value like `temp["anykey"]`. How to convert ruby formatted json string into json object?

I have following json string

```
temp = '{"accept"=>"*/*", "host"=>"localhost:4567", "version"=>"HTTP/1.1", 
       "user_agent"=>"curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3", 
       "http_token"=>"375fe428b1d32787864264b830c54b97"}'
```

Comment: What you have in the post is _not_ a valid JSON, it looks more like a `Hash.to_s` result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try **eval** method on **temp** json string

Example:

```
eval(temp)
```

This will return following hash

```
{"accept"=>"*/*", "host"=>"localhost:4567", "version"=>"HTTP/1.1", "user_agent"=>"curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3", "http_token"=>"375fe428b1d32787864264b830c54b97"}
```

Hope this will help.

Thanks

Comment: Just keep in mind, it's [eval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty) - the same can be achieved in a (IMO) more ruby way using [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23646456/2224331) :) Happy JSON parsing :D

Comment: Thank you so much buddy you made my day ummmaaahhh

Answer (score 11):

Do you know about [JSON.parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) ?

```
require 'json'

my_hash = JSON.parse('{"hello": "goodbye"}')
puts my_hash["hello"] => "goodbye"
```

Answer (score 5):

if your parse this string to ruby object, it will return a ruby Hash object, you can get it like this
You can install the **json gem** for Ruby

```
gem install json
```

You would require the gem in your code like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
```

Then you can parse your JSON string like this:

```
ruby_obj = JSON.parse(json_string)
```

There are also other implementations of JSON for Ruby:

- [YAJL C Bindings for Ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby)
- [JSON::Stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream)

Answer (score 1):

To convert a Ruby hash to json string, simply call to_json.

```
require 'json'

temp = {"accept"=>"*/*", "host"=>"localhost:4567", "version"=>"HTTP/1.1", 
   "user_agent"=>"curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3", 
   "http_token"=>"375fe428b1d32787864264b830c54b97"}
temp.to_json
```

Comment: i did that temp.to_json gives me "{\"user_agent\"=>\"curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3\", \"host\"=>\"localhost:4567\", \"version\"=>\"HTTP/1.1\", \"http_token\"=>\"375fe428b1d32787864264b830c54b97\", \"accept\"=>\"*/*\"}"

Comment: i stored it in t1 and then access like t1['version']. it doesn't give me value of key 'version' but it gives me key itself 'version'