# Jekyll access data files from inside a plugin

Tags: ruby, plugins, jekyll

How do we access information inside the "_data" folder from inside a "_plugin"?

for example I have `_data/items.yml`

```
item
  data1: info
  data2: moreinfo
```

inside my plugin in the render method I want to be able to

```
def render(context)
  <<--MARKUP.strip
  <p>#{site.data.items.data1}</p>
  MARKUP
end
```

Any ideas?
I have been able to get site.data.items but I have not been able to access the children elements (data1, data2)

Comment: Hi Helmut, Have you found out a solution? I'm looking for the same question

Comment: hey @artu-hnrq, you can see what I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43290361/209904

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use a combination of two answers:

How to pass items to my plugin:
[Custom Liquid tag with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29480950/custom-liquid-tag-with-two-parameters)

parse and access json data:
[How to convert ruby formatted json string to json hash in ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646347/how-to-convert-ruby-formatted-json-string-to-json-hash-in-ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Your data file `_data/items.yml` has an `item` key as well.

```
item
  data1: info
  data2: moreinfo
```

So `data1` is actually accessed by **`site.data.items.item.data1`** and
`data2` by **`site.data.items.item.data2`**

Comment: Thanks for the comment and although site.data.items.item.data1 and so forth work great I am looking to how to access the data from within a plugin.

Comment: I had to choose the syntax `site.data["items"]` not `site.data.items`