# Get value from string representing local variable

Tags: ruby, local-variables

I have a local variable name as a string, and need to get its value.

```
variable = 22
"variable".to_variable?
```

How can I get the value `22` form the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval`.

```
variable = 22
eval("variable")
# => 22
```

However [`eval` can be nasty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty). If you dont mind declaring an instance variable, you can do something like this too:

```
@variable = 22
str = "variable"
instance_variable_get("@#{str}")
# => 22
```

Comment: There is no need for `eval` here, just use [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I learned about binding just today through [sawa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30840502/3035830). I knew eval was bad so mentioned that in my answer. But thanks for pointing out.. :)

Comment: eval is potentially dangerous

Answer (score 42):

```
binding.local_variable_get("variable")
# => 22
```

Comment: Is there a way to guard against errors if no variable exists with that name?

Answer (score 0):

use [`eval()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) method:

```
variable = 22
eval "variable" #"variable".to_variable?
# => 22
```

Comment: There is no need for `eval` here, just use [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get).

Comment: eval is potentially dangerous