# Accessing a variable's name from an object

Tags: ruby, variables

Given an object:

```
object_name = "hello"
```

is there any way to get the variable's name `"object_name"`? I need to create a string with the variable's name and the value in it, e.g.

```
"The name of the variable is 'object_name' and its value is 'hello'"
```

I tried:

```
object_name.object_id
# => 20084556
```

Comment: Of course not. ...

Comment: ... and hopefully never will be ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get value from string representing local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840127/get-value-from-string-representing-local-variable)

Comment: @mdesantis, AFAIU OP doesn't have the variable name, just the variable identity.

Comment: Oh so OP wants the variable name starting from `object_id` value, thank you I didn't get that part

Comment: I have the feeling that OP wanted something way simpler and will be completely confused by our interpretation when he sees the answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
def find_var(in_binding, object_id)
  name = in_binding.local_variables.find do |name|
    in_binding.local_variable_get(name).object_id == object_id
  end

  [name, in_binding.local_variable_get(name)]
end

the_answer = 42
find_var binding, the_answer.object_id # => [:the_answer, 42]

foo = 'bar'
baz = [foo]
find_var binding, baz.first.object_id # => [:foo, "bar"]
```

Obvious downfall - two variables pointing to the same object. Aka

```
a = b = 42
```

Comment: Instead of using `object_id`, you could compare the objects via `equal?`

Comment: @Stefan, you can. OP wanted `object_id` for some reason in the question. I'm not sure what possible use case this can have anyway.

Comment: I see. I thought this was the OP's attempt to get the variable's name.

Comment: Concerning the downfall: call the method `find_vars`, replace `find` with `select` and let it return an array. If you want just the first value then you can call `find_vars()[0]`.

Comment: @mdesantis, yes, but I expect that if I call `whatever binding, b.object_id`, where `a = b = 42`, I should get `b` back, not `a` or `[a, b]`.

Comment: Well no, I do not, why a value should be bound just to one single variable name?

Comment: @mdesantis, well it's not but that is what OP is asking for the way I understand it.

Comment: Yes actually it is a refactoring: it's better to write methods that conceptually do the things they should do and adapt your code to it, instead of writing a method that do exactly what you want, but has a conceptual flaw. in this case, in your "backend" code the method should be pluralized, since the bound variables can be more then one. Then in your "frontend" code you use just the first var name. If you write the code in this way, you can omit the downfall part, think about it. It's just a refactoring matter anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can come up with is something along these lines:

```
binding.local_variables.each do |var|
  puts "The name of the variable is '#{var}' and its value is '#{eval(var.to_s)}'"
  # or
  # puts "The name of the variable is '#{var}' and its value is '#{binding.local_variable_get(var)}'"
end
# The name of the variable is 'object_name' and its value is 'hello'
```

Of course this will output all local variables that are currently in scope and, well, `eval`.

Comment: you can use `binding.local_variable_get("variable")` instead of `eval` http://stackoverflow.com/a/30840502/584552

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
object_name = "hello"
var_name = File.readlines(__FILE__)[__LINE__ - 2][/\w+(?=\s*=)/]
puts "Variable named '#{var_name}' has value '#{eval(var_name)}'"

> ruby /tmp/d.rb
#⇒ Variable named 'object_name' has value 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while, but I solved this eventually. Thanks to all for the above answers. Here are the feature file, step definitions and methods I used to work it out.

```
Feature: try and work out a simple version of the f2d pages that could be used for all

  Scenario Outline: first go
    Given I set up an object for these things
      | page_1   | page_2   |
      | <page_1> | <page_2> |
    Then I create objects and output two things for one

    Examples:
      | page_1    | page_2      |
      | elephants | scary pants |
```

Step Definitions:

```
Given(/^I set up an object for these things$/) do |table|
  set_up_a_hash_from_a_table(table)
end

Then(/^I create objects and output two things for one$/) do
  do_something_with_a_hash
end
```

Methods:

```
def set_up_a_hash_from_a_table(table)
  @objects = Hash.new
  @summary = Array.new
  data = table.hashes

  data.each do |field_data|
    @objects['page_1'] = field_data['page_1']
    @objects['page_2'] = field_data['page_2']
  end
end

def do_something_with_a_hash

  show_me_page_1

  show_me_page_2

  puts "Summary is #{@summary}"

end

def show_me_page_1
  do_stuff_for_a_page('page_1')
end

def show_me_page_2
  do_stuff_for_a_page('page_2')
 end

def do_stuff_for_a_page(my_object)
  puts "key is #{my_object} and value is #{@objects[my_object]}"
  @summary.push("#{my_object} - #{@objects[my_object]}")
  end
```

Result:

```
#=> key is page_1 and value is elephants

#=> key is page_2 and value is scary pants

#=> Summary is ["page_1 - elephants", "page_2 - scary pants"]
```