# Change string to hash with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have ugly string that looks like this:

```
"\"New\"=>\"0\""
```

Which will be the best way to converting it into hash object?

Comment: `JSON.parse "{#{you_ugly_string.gsub('=>',':')}}"`

Comment: It not works:
JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"New":"0"'

Comment: I tried and it works for me. Probably you are ignoring `{` and `}` in the string

Comment: This looks like the result of a `Hash#inspect`. Instead of trying to parse this string into a proper data structure, you should instead try to use the original hash and don't convert it into a string first. This data has no business being in a string there and you should save you the hassle of trying to extract it there..

Comment: Please show the hash you desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with `"\"New\"=>\"0\""` is it does not look like a Hash. So first step should be to manipulate it to look like a Hash:

```
"{" + a + "}"
# => "{\"New\"=>\"0\"}"
```

Now once you have a hash looking string you can convert it into Hash like this:

```
eval "{" + a + "}"
# => {"New"=>"0"}
```

However there is still one issue, `eval` [is not safe and inadvisable to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/637431/3035830). So lets manipulate the string further to make it look json-like and use `JSON.parse`:

```
require `json`
JSON.parse ("{" + a + "}").gsub("=>",":")
# => {"New"=>"0"}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `JSON.parse(string.gsub("=>", ":"))`

Comment: you need to manipulate string, else you'll get `JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '"New":"0"'`

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex to pull out the key and value. Then create `Hash` directly

```
Hash[*"\"New\"=>\"0\"".scan(/".*?"/)]
```

Hard to nail down the *best* way if you can't tell us exactly the general format of those strings. You may not even need the regex. eg

```
Hash[*"\"New\"=>\"0\"".split('"').values_at(1,3)]
```

Also works for `"\"Rocket\"=>\"=>\""`