# How to pass array as argument inside ARGV

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a ruby script that takes two inputs for `ARGV`. The second input is an *array* of files. I'm having trouble iterating through the file *array* passed to `ARGV`. Here is what I have so far:

```
arg1, FILES = ARGV

FILES.each do |fname| 
    #do something with fname 
end
```

I'm running my script from the command line like this:

```
ruby myScript.rb arg1 ['path/to/file1.jpg', '/path/to/file2.jpg']
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> zsh: bad pattern: [path/to/file1.jpg,

Enclosing the *array* argument in single quotes like this:

```
ruby myScript.rb arg1 '['path/to/file1.jpg', '/path/to/file2.jpg']'
```

Produces a different error, as it interprets it as a *String* rather than *array*.

How can I accomplish this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
arg1, *FILES = ARGV
```

and don't place any brackets or commas during invocation:

```
ruby myScript.rb arg1 file1 file2 file3
```

---

**EDIT**: If you want to add another argument, you can do:

```
arg1, arg2, *FILES = ARGV
```

or

```
arg1, *FILES, arg2 = ARGV
```

Comment: Does the asterisk denote an array? Also, what if a third argument is added after files?

Comment: @FionaCat86, the `*` will say *"put the first argument in `arg1` and the rest in `FILES`"*. So `FILES` will be an array. If you want to add another argument, add it after `arg1`. Note that CLIs don't have a concept of *"array"* in general, this is not something Ruby specific. You can parse arguments enclosed in `[]`, but there is no out of the box solution for it.

Comment: I ran this and it produced error "undefined method `each' for "path/to/file1.jpg":String (NoMethodError)" Seems like it's just looking at the first string rather than the array as a whole?

Comment: @FionaCat86, I get this if I remove the `*`. It works just fine if it's there.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an array as a command-line argument. All arguments are passed as strings.

But given your code, you could just pass the arguments like this:

```
$ ruby myScript.rb arg1 path/to/file1.jpg /path/to/file2.jpg
```

And then, change your first line of code to this:

```
arg1, *FILES = ARGV
```

And after, `arg1 = 'arg1'` and `FILES = ['path/to/file1.jpg', 'path/to/file2.jpg']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can either split manually, e.g. `arg, arr = ARGV[0], ARGV[1..-1]` or use the [splat operator](http://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/ruby-pearls-vol-1-the-splat) `arg, *arr = ARGV`

Answer (score 0):

```
arg1, _files = ARGV
files = eval(_files)
files.each { |f| ... }
```

But there are reasons to not use `eval` (see [Is 'eval' supposed to be nasty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty)).

You might pass the files list as a json string and then do `JSON.parse` on it to be safer, e.g.:

```
require 'json'
arg1, _files = ARGV
files = JSON.parse(_files)
files.each { |f| ... }

#> ruby myScript.rb arg1 '["path/to/file1.jpg", "/path/to/file2.jpg"]'
```