# Include all the ruby files from a directory inside a block as inline code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Structure of ruby file is as shown below,

```
market
  |__abcd
       |__classification
              |__for_sale_mobile_phone.rb
              |__catalogues
                  |__mobile_phone_brands
                      |__acer.rb
                      |__apple.rb
                      |__samsung.rb
```

In `for_sale_mobile_phone.rb`, I like to include all brands of `mobile_phone_brands` under a block.

I m trying to include brands in below fashion,

```
 .....
    c.tree_field :brand, { child_key: :model } do |b|
      Dir[
        File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/catalogues/mobile_phone_brands/*.rb'
      ].each { |brand| load brand }

      b.required = true
    end
.....
```

here is how brand file looks like. for example, `apple.rb`

```
b.value "apple" do |brand|
  brand.value "6plus"
  brand.value "6s"
  brand.value "6s-plus"
  brand.value "se"
  brand.value "7"
  brand.value "7-plus"
  brand.value "other-model"
end
```

I m getting below error,

```
undefined local variable or method `b' on line 1: apple.rb
```

How can I include file under a block scope?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding this correctly.  You want to include variables from other files as local variables in another file?

Comment: You could try using an instance variable for `@b` instead of b

Comment: I just want to make `apple.rb` inline @ called place

Answer (score 1):

You should separate file "loading" from function execution. Redefine your file like this.

```
class AppleLoader

  def self.load(b)
    b.value "apple" do |brand|
      brand.value "6plus"
      brand.value "6s"
      brand.value "6s-plus"
      brand.value "se"
      brand.value "7"
      brand.value "7-plus"
      brand.value "other-model"
    end
  end
end
```

On top of file you load required classes like this:

```
require '/catalogues/mobile_phone_brands/apple_loader.rb'
```

And when you want to load Apple brand in the `b` object:

```
AppleLoader.load b
```

**Better Approach:**
To me it feels like `Apple.rb` defers from `Samsung.rb` only in terms of data. If that's the case, and functionality for both of them are same then I would rather:

1. put that data in a Yaml file(`brands.yml`) instead of rb file.

   ```
       brands:
        apple: ["6plus", "6s"]
        samsung: ["galaxy"]
   ```
2. Have just one common loader called `BrandLoader`

   ```
   class BrandLoader

     def self.load(b, brand_name, values)
       b.value brand_name do |brand|
         brand_values.each do |value|
           brand.value value
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. Iterate over brands by reading Yaml

   ```
   configurations = YAML.load "brands.yml"
   configurations["brands"].each do |brand_name, values|
     BrandLoader.load(b, brand_name, values)
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, But I figured it out

Comment: Agarwal: Can give upvote for your attempt, Which works perfectly but solution below I figured out make it simple

Comment: I had a look at it, though it works but not a recommended way of doing things in ruby. When you have performance and maintainability concerns, you should switch

Answer (score 0):

The way I figured out is by using `eval` but cautious read up [is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty), `eval` works for me as I'm not using user input.

To make any code in different file, execute as the code written in the place of call. Use `eval(File.read(file_path)`

```
 .....
    c.tree_field :brand, { child_key: :model } do |b|
      Dir[
        File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/catalogues/mobile_phone_brands/*.rb'
      ].each { |brand| eval(File.read(brand)) }

      b.required = true
    end
.....
```