# How to change "string" to date month or year in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

How to convert a string like this

```rb
    "6.months" => 6.months
    "6.years" => 6.years
```

I know how to split these characters but I don't know how to make the string as an object of the date class.

Thanks

Comment: What do you `6.months` expect to be? A string without quotes? A method call (there is no `months` method on integer)? Where are the strings coming from?

Comment: I have a string "6.months"  i want it to be `6.months` so i can add the date like this `Date.today + 6.months`

Comment: If you're using Rails or just ActiveSupport use the proper tags, Ruby alone does not have a `#months` method for integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
require "active_support/core_ext/integer/time"

'6.months'.split('.').then{ |n, t| n.to_i.public_send t }

#=> 6 months
```

So:

```
Date.today + '6.months'.split('.').then{ |n, t| n.to_i.public_send t }
```

---

Or patching the String class:

```
module MyStringPatch
  def to_integer_time
    self.split('.').then{ |n, t| n.to_i.public_send t }
  end
end

String include MyStringPatch

Date.today + '6.months'.to_integer_time
```

---

Or if you trust the evil `eval` (see comments), you can also just do:

```
Date.today + eval('6.months')
```

By the way, as pointed by @AlekseiMatiushkin

> If it comes from the user input, `#public_send` might also be dangerous

Comment: Seems to be evil :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637421/is-eval-supposed-to-be-nasty

Comment: Nah. If it comes from the user input, `#public_send` might also be dangerous. If not, `#eval` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I used your comments for an edit. If disagree I'm rolling back.

Comment: Why could I disagree? Sure, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are completely sure you have a valid object of `ActiveSupport::Duration`, you can do something like the following:

```
amount, time_span = '6.months'.split('.')
duration = amount.to_i.public_send(time_span)

Date.today + duration
```

`amount` is the `String` 6 and `time_span` is the `String` months.
`duration` is the `ActiveSupport::Duration` 6 months.
The result will be the present day in 6 month, which is a `Date`

Comment: `#public_send` should be enough, no need to use `#send`

Comment: I want to add `Date.today + 6.months`

Comment: `amount.to_i.send(time_span)` will evaluate to `6.months`

Comment: What is the value of `amount`?

Comment: I try that but the value is not `6.months` but `6 months`

Comment: `6.months` is not a value. `6` is an `Integer` and `month` is a method. Calling this will result in `6 months` which is an instance of `ActiveSupport::Duration`.